# Integrate window tester with eclipse for testing UI

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, automated-tests

We are planning to automate testing of my eclipse application GUI using window tester. Version of eclipse is oxygen.

Please inform me how to integrate window tester with eclipse application. I do not see any window tester plugin in eclipse market place. If not, Which GUI testing framework can i use to test my eclipse application.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have personally used first two types of the frameworks:

1. [SWTBot](https://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/)
2. [RCPTT](https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/documentation/userguide/getstarted/)
3. [Jubula](http://www.eclipse.org/jubula/)
4. [RedDeer](http://www.eclipse.org/reddeer/)

`RCPTT` is focused on creating and running UI/System test for RCP/SWT applications. It is an alternative or addition to the open source projects `SWTBot` or `Jubula`. All of them have their specific advantages and disadvantages, `RCPTT` uses a very different approach than that of `SWTBot` or `Jubula`.

`SWTBot` is a Java API to consume while writing tests (can be JUnit, 
TestNG...), which makes it very easy to use for Java developers.

`Jubula` has its own XML-based languages to write tests. Аlso
 uses an embedded database and thus differs internally most from the others.

`RCPTT` using [Eclipse Command Language](https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/documentation/userguide/ecl/) to write tests.

Thanks to [@howlger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6505250/howlger) for help.

Comment: If you expand your answer, I can delete my answer: RedDeer is missing and [ECL](https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/documentation/userguide/ecl/) is not XML based but can be persisted to an XML file. Jubula uses an embedded database and thus differs internally most from the others.

Answer (score 0):

Jubula test can be written either with a UI, which can be used without any programming  experience or with an API for Java.

I would have written this in the comments for @MBaev but i was not able due to low reputation