# Run a program in debug mode in eclipse in command line

Tags: eclipse

For several reasons I must test my program with multiple computer restart.
So I need at the computer startup, eclipse open and the tested program runs in eclipse (in debug mode if possible).

Can you give me a command line or another way to do that. I just need when I open eclipse or when I use the given command line, the program  automatically start

Thank you

Comment: One possibility is to use a UI testing tool: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51591521/6505250

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Linux OS (not sure on Win, Mac), Eclipse (or other apps) can be automated with `xdotool` utility. Assuming your app has run at least once in debug mode within Eclipse so it exists an entry on Debug history, a Bash script could do the following actions

-Edit the script below to set the correct `position` value for the app.
-Launch `Eclipse`.
-Wait some time until is fully up.
-Execute the following command sequence:

```
#!/bin/bash

position=6

#find Eclipse app window IDs, keep the last one
e_wid=$(xdotool search --class Eclipse | gawk 'END{print $0}')
# Create basic command string
cmd="xdotool windowactivate --sync $e_wid"
# Send key strokes with some delay in between
# Open Run menu
$cmd key Alt+r 
sleep 1
# select Debug option
$cmd key h
sleep 0.5
# pick the sixth option in that menu
$cmd key $position
```

It's recommended to mark the app as a favorite so it gets a constant order in the menu.
To see another example, check this [mluis7 gist at Github](https://gist.github.com/mluis7/bc7bdf7f4a2fb8e35c3b113123a674bd).