# How can I restart or exit my eclipse through command line

Tags: eclipse, command-line, exit, restart, p2-director

I am uninstalling an application in eclipse through command line (by using p2director), and if I want that to take effect I wanted to restart my eclipse or exit my eclipse and reopen it for next installation.

For that I have tried the -clean(as the first command) command as below,  but that does not work for me.

```
cmd_line_path> eclipse.exe -clean
```

Can I get some inputs how can the same can be done ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you mean Eclipse is already running when you execute that command? So you want to stop the current Eclipse and start a new one? There is no command line that would do that.

Comment: Yes that is my requirement. So, is there a way to close my currently opened eclipse alone without restarting a new one ?

Comment: No, there is no Eclipse command line to stop a currently running Eclipse. There might be some 'kill' type command provided by the operating system.

Comment: `eclipse.exe` means you are on Windows, so use `taskkill /T /IM eclipse.exe` to shutdown Eclipse from the command line: https://superuser.com/a/727757

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51660840/2834978) should help to automate that.