# Start Eclipse via Jenkins with variables passed from jenkins into eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jenkins

we are using an Eclipse version that is heavily modified to edit and build structured text. In order to do automated nightly builds our partner gave us a functionality to start of autobuilds of our tasks. I want to enable jenkins to start these autobuilds. In order to do that I want to start eclipse via jenkins and want to trigger the script "Autobuild.js" that builds the project that is given by the jenkins. so i need a way to pass a variable through the command line or trigger specific scripts. Is this possible?

Comment: You could use an [UI testing tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51591521/6505250), use [Eclipse EASE](https://www.eclipse.org/ease/) (with [`onStartup`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EASE/Scripts) and environment variables) or write your own plug-in for that.

Comment: Hi howlger, i actually use EASE already with  #onStartup       : 10  to start the script but i have no clue to pass on variables from jenkins to eclipse

Comment: Does running Eclipse with `eclipse -vmargs -Dfoo=bar` and in the script `System.getProperty("foo")` work?

Comment: That doesn't work, the script does not know "System" System is not defined. I got it: 
var Foo = java.lang.System.getProperty("foo");  does the trick

Answer (score 0):

For that one of the following can be used:

- an [UI testing tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51591521/6505250)
- own plug-in
- [**Eclipse EASE**](https://www.eclipse.org/ease/) with [`onStartup`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EASE/Scripts) and **environment variables**:

  1. start Eclipse with `eclipse -vmargs -Dfoo=bar`
  2. read environment variable `foo` via `var foo = java.lang.System.getProperty("foo");`